# get only visible radio buttons from form jquery

Tags: jquery

I have aform which has lots of radio button both visible and hidden. I need to get only the visible radio buttons and do some manipulations. I am trying the below code. But its not working. Can somebody please help me in this.

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function () {
    var returnVal = true;
    $.each($('.input-container[data-validation=required]'), function (idx, group) {
        $(group).next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
        var unchecked = $(group).find(':radio').filter(':visible');
        if (!unchecked.is(':checked')) {
            var title = unchecked.attr('title');
            $(group).after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>' + title + '</li></ul>');
            returnVal = false;
        }
    });
});
```

One group has 4-5 radio buttons. I need to check any of the radio button in the group is checked or not. So I am not sure if the above code is really checking if any one radio button in the group is checked or not. Because even after all the radio buttons
are checked, its giving returnVal as false. If I try to alert returnVal, first it gives true and after that it gives all false.

Answer (score 5):

You can just make one selector and skip the `if :checked` statement

```
var unchecked = $(group).find(':radio:checked:visible');
```

Now, rather than run the `if` loop, just run an `each` iteration on these and do your manipulation.

Comment: This is not working..$(group).find(':radio:checked:visible').each(function(){..}); Whe I wrote like this its nt going insid ethe loop

Comment: Hmm...mind making a quick fiddle or posting the relevant HTML?

Comment: yes its working...atcually that is not the problem..can u check this fiddle please. Here one radio group is hidden. So even if i select the first two radio groups, since the hidden one is not selected, its always returning false..How can I handle this?http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/44/

Comment: @tyme..Here is the modified fiddle with ur suggestion..here when the user doesn't select anything it should alert false. and display error message. If the user selects both and submit, it should display true.Hope i didnt confude u http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/45/